# GZIPOutputStream length for socket usage

Tags: java, sockets, http, gzip

I'm developing a little webserver in Java with sockets. I made it work like HTTP, with `Connection: keep-alive`, and so on.
Now, I'd like to compress (GZIP) the data sent.

To ensure the `Connection: keep-alive` is respected, I never close the socket. That's why I need to send in EVERY response the `content-length`. It's easy to do with normal file.
This is how I do it.

```
out.println(HTTP_VERSION + " 200 OK");
out.println("Content-Type: "+Files.probeContentType(f.toPath())+"; charset=UTF-8\nContent-Length:"+f.length()+"\n");
Files.copy(f.toPath(), so.getOutputStream());
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the size of my `GZIPOutputStream`.

This is what I'd like to do.

```
GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
out.println(HTTP_VERSION + " 200 OK");
out.println("Content-Type: "+Files.probeContentType(f.toPath())+"; charset=UTF-8\nContent-Encoding: gzip\nContent-Length:"+SIZE HERE+"\n");
Files.copy(f.toPath(), gos);
gos.finish();
```

Any idea please? Thank you. And merry christmas!

### UPDATE

I managed to solve my problem. This is the final code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
Files.copy(f.toPath(), gos);
gos.finish();
out.println("Content-Type: "+Files.probeContentType(f.toPath())+"; charset=UTF-8\nContent-Encoding: gzip\nContent-Length:"+bos.toByteArray().length+"\n");
bos.writeTo(so.getOutputStream());
```

Thanks JB Nizet and Brant Unger

Comment: You could gzip to ByteArrayOutputStream in memory, and then send the bytes. Or you could use chunked transfer (but this will require more work). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: I recommend doing the writing to a byte array (in memory) like the above comment mentions. Then you can just get the length of the the byte array and input it where you have 'size here'

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try it and let you know if it's ok!

Comment: @RomainPellerin can you add your solution as an actual answer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. This is the final code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
Files.copy(f.toPath(), gos);
gos.finish();
out.println("Content-Type: "+Files.probeContentType(f.toPath())+"; charset=UTF-8\nContent-Encoding: gzip\nContent-Length:"+bos.toByteArray().length+"\n");
bos.writeTo(so.getOutputStream());
```

Thanks JB Nizet and Brant Unger